# How to store data in new rows automatically using python's pandas and numpy library

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I want to store data in the 2nd row of the CSV file. but it's overriding the 1st row each time. How to do it? I used a loop for storing data in the 2nd row. but it's not happening. Is there anything I am missing?

```
  import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    a=1
    def table_driven_agent(percept):
        location=['A','B']
        status=['clean','dirty']
        percepts=[]
        table=[location,status]
        percepts.append(percept)
        action = tableDrivenVaccum(percept,table)
        if action == 'dirty':
          action = dirty(percept[1])
        return(action)
    def tableDrivenVaccum(percept,table):
        for i in table:
            if i[0] == percept[0]:
                return(i[1])
    def dirty(percept):
        if percept == 'A':
            return('Go to B')
        elif percept =='B':
            return('Go to A')
    while( a<10):
        percept = list(map(str,input("Enter the status and position:").split(',')))
        action = table_driven_agent(percept)
        print(action)
        dict = {'action': action, 'percept': percept}
        df= pd.DataFrame(dict) 
        df.to_csv(r'index.csv', index =False, header=True)
        a=1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself by reading old CSV file and merging and put it into the CSV file.you have to create CSV file index.csv like mine. then put column name as percent and action to work. without CSV file in your code location will give an error. it will automatically merge the latest input in the CSV file without deleting any row. 
**NOTE: index.csv, percent, and action is just an example. you can use yours as well.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
i = 1
def table_driven_agent(percept):
    location=['A','B']
    status=['clean','dirty']
    percepts=[]
    table=[location,status]
    percepts.append(percept)
    action = tableDrivenVaccum(percept,table)
    if action == 'dirty':
      action = dirty(percept[1])
    return(action)
def tableDrivenVaccum(percept,table):
    for i in table:
        if i[0] == percept[0]:
            return(i[1])
def dirty(percept):
    if percept == 'A':
        return('Go to B')
    elif percept =='B':
        return('Go to A')
while i < 6:        
    percept = list(map(str,input("Enter the status and position:").split(',')))
    action = table_driven_agent(percept)
    print(action)
    
    df_old =pd.read_csv('index.csv')
    newData=[[percept,action]]
    colNames =df_old.columns

    df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=newData, columns=colNames)
    df_complete = pd.concat([df_old,df_new],axis=0)
    df_complete.to_csv('index.csv',index=False)
    
    #dict = {'percept': percept, 'action': action}
    #df= pd.DataFrame(dict) 
    #df.to_csv(r'index.csv', index =False, header=True,mode='a')
    i =1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Writing to csv creates a new one and replace current csv. That's why it writes into the first row: it actually delete previous and writes into blank file.

What you are looking for is to append `df` into current csv. That can be done by:

```py
df.to_csv('index.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=True)
```

Notice I added `mode='a'`. It means mode=append. Default `mode` is `'w'`, means "write" (overwrite).

That way `df` is being added to the last row of current csv.

If your csv has more then 2 rows and you want to change only second row, You should load all your csv to a dataframe first. Then you can change only second row (`df.loc[1,:]=...`) and then save all of it to csv (`df.to_csv(r'index.csv', index =False, header=True`)

Comment: Why have you used a raw string for the path `index.csv` ?

Comment: just copied his line and added `mode`. Didn't though about it